# Moving people to voice channels

Tags: c#, discord.net

I seem to have this weird error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
await userName.ModifyAsync(x =>
{

    x.Channel = Program.client.GetChannel(588025239103995904) as IVoiceChannel;

});
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Discord.IVoiceChannel` to `Discord.Optional<Discord.IVoiceChannel>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `Optional<T>`:

```cs
await user.ModifyAsync(x =>
{
    var voiceChannel = Program.client.GetChannel(588025239103995904) as IVoiceChannel;
    x.Channel = Optional.Create(voiceChannel);

});
```